# Use Collectors.groupingby to create a map to a set

Tags: java, set, java-stream, grouping

I know how to create a `Map<T, List<U>>` , using `Collectors.groupingBy`:

`Map<Key, List<Item>> listMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s.key));`

How would I modify that code to create `Map<Key, Set<Item>>`? Or can I not do it using `stream` and so have to create it manually using a for loop etc.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toSet()` as a downstream in [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Map<Key, Set<Item>> map = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.key, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a downstream collector like this:

```
Map<Key, Set<Item>> listMap = items.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.key, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I also like the non-stream solution sometimes:

```
 Map<Key, Set<Item>> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
 items.forEach(x -> yourMap.computeIfAbsent(x.getKey(), ignoreMe -> new HashSet<>()).add(x));
```

If you really wanted you could exercise to do the same via `compute/merge` methods too